# How can I update a MongoDB document with python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, discord.py

what I'm trying to do is to update a MongoDB document with python and discord.py, but the code i've put doesn't work.

```
elif string2 == "add":
    if string3 == "administrator":
        cur = coll.find({"_id" : string1.id})
        for doc in cur:
            if doc["perm"] == "administrator":
                await self.bot.say("Permission {} already found on db for user {}".format(string3, string1.name))
            else:
                db.users.update_one({"_id" : string1.id, "name" : string1.name, "perm" : "administrator"}, upsert=False)
                await self.bot.say("Permissions updated on db for user {}".format(string1.name))
```

The following is the error.

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: update_one() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update'
```

Document from users collection:

```
_id: "191598787410526208"
name: "Stevyb0t"
perm: "administrator"
```

Comment: You need to pass the second parameter to `update_one` in order to update the document and avoid such errors. It will look something like this, `db.users.update_one({}, {}, upsert=False)`

Comment: @NileshSingh , it says that "update only works with $ operators".

Comment: Would help a lot if you could use the [edit] link to update your question and show us a sample document from the `users` collection

Comment: @chridam , done.

Comment: Like what @NileshSingh said, try `db.users.update_one({"_id" : string1.id}, {"$set": {"name" : string1.name, "perm" : "administrator"}}, upsert=False)`

Comment: @chridam, thanks! It worked well.

Comment: @chridam you can make your comment as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially what other people have commented but with some formatting to make it more legible:

```
db.users.update_one(
    {"_id": string1.id},
    {"$set":
        {"name": string1.name,
        "perm": "administrator"
    }})
```

I also removed `upsert=False` since that's the default value anyway so you don't need to specify it - though of course being explicit can be helpful

**Edit**: read all the comments, suggestion was already made to make accepted comment an answer so here it is. My answer is no different from that comment

Answer (score 2):

If your **id** is a string, you *may* need to convert it to an ObjectId. Also, you can print the result of the update, and check success:

```
from bson import ObjectId

result = db.users.update_one(
             {"_id": ObjectId(string1.id)},
             {"$set":
                 {"name": string1.name,
                  "perm": "administrator"}
             })

logger.debug('update result: {}'.format(result.raw_result))
if result.matched_count > 0:
    # Success code goes here
    pass
else:
    # Failure code goes here
    pass
```